# iexpress installer package

Tags: winforms

I am making an installer package to run two .exe file. I want to run .exe file one by one.
for that i have to make .bat file? Does anyone know how to make this .bat fie. I am using iexpress for installer package.

Answer (score 0):

A batch file (.bat) is actually just a list of commands. You can safely edit it using Notepad. By default, Right Click > Edit will open it in Notepad.

An example of a batch file:

```
@echo off
echo "testing cool right?"
pause
```

In your case, you can write something like this:

```
pathname/to/first.exe
pathname/to/second.exe
```

Comment: i want to add my .bat file in installer package. So that it will run on click of package and will proceed to further installation of 2 exe file.

Comment: Then just add it in? and make sure that all 3 files - batch file and the 2 exe are in the same folder. It's like writing command prompt commands all together.